# How safe is "git" with an unreliable connection?

Tags: git

I am using git for source control and push my changes to a repository on a server on the internet for safe keeping.

I can do some small amounts of coding on a laptop on a train, which has a wifi internet connection but it's not *that* reliable and occasionally drops out or becomes unusable slow. My question is what happens if my connection is lost during a "git push"? Will I end up with a corrupted or half updated git repository? And if so, how difficult is it to recover it?

Comment: I would imagine its like SVN and its a transaction.. so if the update fails,  nothing in the repository changes.  I dont know enough about it for a proper answer

Comment: I would hope so too, but would like to know for sure :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Git will not corrupt or "half update" your Git repository just because of a failed or slow connection. It's very robust and I would still feel comfortable using it even in the most arduous circumstances.

The actual `push` function is implemented in essentially two steps (in the case of a fast-forward push, which should always be the case):

- upload all objects reachable from your current branch head and not reachable from the remote branch head
- update the remote branch head to point to the latest commit

The first operation is idempotent, so if it fails for any reason halfway through, you can simply run it again to get everything up to date. The second operation is atomic and only happens once all the new objects are uploaded.

Comment: If the push fails during a large update in the first step (due to conn loss), does git pick up where it left off when the connection recovers, or start over?

Comment: @Mark Elliot: Objects may be transferred individually or in "packs". I don't think an incomplete pack file will be stored at the destination if the connection fails, but individual objects probably are.

Comment: @Mark Elliot: it will start over, git uses the refs (updated in the second step) to determine what it should send. See Documentation/technical/send-pack-pipeline.txt for details.

Comment: However, if the internet connection is interrupted, the progress is lost. The next retry will start from the beginning. In other words, it is not restartable or resumable. There has been lots of discussions and tips and tricks to reduce the impact of this issue, but there are some fundamental lower-level work that was yet to be done. It is mainly due to the fact that packfiles are typically mmaped, and therefore git is designed to minimize the number of packfiles it needed to keep open - often trying to keep it at one.

Answer (score 5):

According to Linus git is so well secured on the data area that it would even detect a memory error on the system it's running on. It will simply not apply the packets that arrive at the server that have an invalid checksum, so you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: If I have several local changes to push can I be sure that it won't apply some of them but not others?